# Format of output gdaltransform

Tags: gdal

It's seems that output of [gdaltransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html) in meters. I would like to enter data in geography degrees and get result in degrees. Is it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each system has its native units and GDAL is respecting those. For example EPSG:4326 is using degrees as units while EPSG:3857 is using meters. Therefore if your output is in EPSG:3857 you will get meters but output to EPSG:4326 shows you degrees.

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
10 30
1113194.90793274 3503549.84350438 0

gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:3857 -t_srs epsg:4326 
1113194.90793274 3503549.84350438
10 30 0
```

However, I do not understand what is your aim. Gdaltransform does not move the point anywhere, it is located all the time at the same place on earth. Only the coordinate numbers are different for each coordinate system. If you put EPSG:4326 degrees in and want to get EPSG:4326 degrees out then your input will be equal to the output. Obviously you have some other idea which you should clarify.

Comment: The situation is next. Input meta data in 4326. For displaying on the map (leaflet-js) I need them in 3857. And they should be in degrees.

But now output in meters. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: 3857 is **NOT** in degrees. If the coordinates should be displayed in degrees, they have to be in EPSG:4326.

Comment: So you need to take 3857 coordinates, transform them into 4326 and then show the degrees for your users. Millions of web maps are doing that all the time.